# Resize instance types on Container Engine cluster

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

Some of our containers run better with memory above the instance type currently deployed in our Container Engine cluster.  Is there a recommended practice to rebuild the container engine template for larger instances after the container engine cluster has been created?

For example, go from GCE instances n1-standard-2 to n1-highmem-8 for running containers with above 8GB RAM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an official GKE tutorial for this:

**Migrating workloads to different machine types**
"*This tutorial demonstrates how to migrate workloads running on a GKE cluster to a new set of nodes within the same cluster without incurring downtime for your application. Such a migration can be useful if you want to migrate your workloads to nodes with a different machine type.*"

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/migrating-node-pool

Answer (score 21):

Container Engine doesn't currently have an API for doing this, but since it uses a [Compute Engine instance group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/) for the nodes in your cluster, you can actually update it without needing GKE's help. In the Developers Console, copy the [instance template](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates) that looks like "gke--"  and modify the machine type in it, then edit the similarly named instance group to use the new template. You can find these options under `Compute > Compute Engine > Instance templates` and `Compute > Compute Engine > Instance groups`, respectively.

Comment: be aware that doing an API upgrade will rollback your nodes to the previous specifications. This caused my applications to swap because of lack of memory

Comment: @Andre What do you mean by API upgrade? Google Cloud SDK or Kubernetes or something else?

Comment: > `gcloud container clusters upgrade CLUSTER_NAME` . Outlined here: https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/clusters/upgrade

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, when copying the instance template and creating it the create action hangs. There seems to be a JS Error "cannot read property 'name' of null at getDiskTypeLocalizedName" which is related to the disk image, which is correct since it probably refers to the GKE container-vm image which is not selectable for me. So resizing is not possible anymore.

Comment: @VincentH. - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137130/creating-an-instance-template-in-gce-is-just-hanging

Comment: Is this not a major limitation for the platform? How does one deal with scaling GKE without downtime? Can you create another cluster and failover?

Comment: @dcgoss It works without downtime. After new instance template is created you can switch current instance group to new template and scale out.

Comment: Now its possible to resize the cluster through gcloud [link](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/release-notes#april_29_2016)

Comment: @alex-robinson I did work smoothly. However, the container engine still shows the old CPU & RAM configuration. Is it possible to somehow force google cloud to update the container cluster view ?

Comment: Do the instances have to be restarted / delete for the instances to used the new instance templates? How is this change meant to be initiated?

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski yes you'd have to delete the instances and let the instance group recreate them. You might want to look into GKE's newer "Node Pool" functionality - https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-pools

Answer (score 15):

A different approach would be:

(1) to create a new node-pool to the GKE cluster with vertically scaled machine types ...

```
$ gcloud container node-pools create pool-n1std2 --zone europe-west1-d --cluster prod-cluster-1 --machine-type  n1-standard-2  --image-type gci --disk-size=250 --num-nodes 3
```

(2) then, migrate the workloads off the old nodes ...

```
$ kubectl drain gke-prod-cluster-1-default-pool-f1eabad5-9ml5 --delete-local-data --force
```

(3) and finally, to delete the old node-pool

```
$ gcloud container node-pools delete default-pool --cluster=prod-cluster-1
```

Notes:

- **Warning: Step 2 deletes node local volumes like `emptyDir` !!!**
- Step 2 needs to be repeated for each node in the pool
- Instead of draining the nodes, one might configure a proper `nodeSelector` to schedule the pods onto the new pool. Label to be matched against would be `cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: pool-n1std2`

Answer (score 4):

- Create a new node pool with a custom machine type, disk-size, num-nodes and with any other required parameters.
- All steps are at
  [**Google Container Engine GKE node pools**](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/05/introducing-Google-Container-Engine-GKE-node-pools.html).

Answer (score 2):

> go from GCE instances n1-standard-2 to n1-highmem-8 for running containers with above 8GB RAM?

Kubernetes 1.12 (Sept. 2018) should provide an official way to manage your existing resource with [kubernetes issue 21](https://github.com/kubernetes/features/issues/21) "Vertical Scaling of Pods" (Or "**VPA**": **Vertical Pod Autoscaler**").

As [announced on the blog](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/09/27/kubernetes-1.12-kubelet-tls-bootstrap-and-azure-virtual-machine-scale-sets-vmss-move-to-general-availability/#additional-notable-feature-updates):

> Vertical Scaling of Pods is now in beta, which makes it possible to vary the resource limits on a pod over its lifetime. In particular, this is valuable for pets (i.e., pods that are very costly to destroy and re-create).

[Warning](https://github.com/kubernetes/features/issues/21#issuecomment-419278673):

This is landing around 1.12 however it is a launch of an independent addon. It is not included in 1.12 Kubernetes release.
Sig-Architecture, at the beginning of this cycle, decided to keep the VPA API as CRD and thus not bind it to any particular K8S release.

See more in:

- "[kubernetes/autoscaler/vertical-pod-autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler)"
- "[Vertical pod autoscaler](https://banzaicloud.com/blog/k8s-vertical-pod-autoscaler/)" from **[Toader Sebastian](https://github.com/stoader)**

[image: https://banzaicloud.com/img/blog/cluster-autoscaler/vertical-pod-autoscaler.png]

That last article from BanzaiCloud is a bit dated (some links are no longer valid), but it still illustrates how you can manage your pod resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can now vertically scale the node pool by changing the node machine attributes. GKE allows you to modify the node pool's configured machine type, disk type, and disk size. It is important to note that when you edit one or more of these machine attributes, GKE updates the nodes to the new configuration using the upgrade strategy configured for the node pool.

```
gcloud container node-pools update POOL_NAME \
--cluster CLUSTER_NAME \
--machine-type MACHINE_TYPE \
--disk-type DISK_TYPE \
--disk-size DISK_SIZE
```

Please find more details [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-pools#change-machine-attributes)