# Creating an Instance Template in GCE is just hanging

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Trying to setup a pilot in GCE to try out GKE.  I'm trying to create a new instance template from a copy of the one created with by the "gcloud container clusters create" with more space per instance and the create is just hanging???  Is there something obvious that I'm not doing?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uixOC.png)

Comment: Create is hanging while creating the google container engine cluster or creating the new instance template?

Comment: Hangs while trying to create the instance template.  Found the issue.  If you only make a change to the startup-script with no other changes.  UI just hangs.   Doesn't seem like this would be expected behavior.

Comment: That definitely sounds like a bug. I'll let the team know.

Comment: @RobertBailey I'm seeing the same issue. Is there another way to copy instance templates? I need to add datastore access to my existing cluster and don't want to have to create a new one from scratch. Thanks

Comment: @toby Have you tried creating the copy of the template using the CLI (gcloud)?

Comment: @RobertBailey I did take a look but was a bit overwhelmed by the amount of stuff in there and not knowing what to change. I'll follow that up and take another look though. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this bug has been fixed. I just copied an instance template for my Google Container Engine cluster in the UI, modified the only the startup script field, and created a new instance template. Please try this again, as I believe it will now work for you as you expect.