# Can you run Kubernetes on Google Container Engine in multiple zones or regions?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

If possible I'd like setup a multi-zone Kubernetes cluster on GCE but when creating a new cluster from the web console I can only select a single zone:

[image]

Is it possible to have a multi-zone or even multi-region Kubernetes cluster on GCE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Container Engine is a zonal service, which means that each cluster runs wholly within a single zone.

If you want to do this manually you can follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302233/resize-instance-types-on-container-engine-cluster/31303169#31303169) to create a new instance template in a different zone and spin up nodes that connect to your existing Kubernetes master. Just be aware that you will be paying for the bandwidth between the nodes and the master between different zones even if they are in the same region (see the [GCE Network Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#network)).