# Vertical scaling of instance groups in google container engine

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

Hi I'm trying out Google container engine and I'm interested in the managed instance groups so that I can scale instances.

Though it only seems possible to use one group for the complete cluster, meaning the same hardware for all instances.

I'm thinking that i dont need the same hardware on some service nodes as i do on the data database nodes for example.

That seems like it would become quite expensive.

Is there a way to have different instance groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct -- Google Container Engine will one create one instance group, which means that your nodes will all have the same machine type.

You can manually add extra nodes of a different type to your cluster by creating your own instance group (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31303169/4215791) but Google Container Engine won't know about the group (which has caused other folks issues when they want to do updates).

Comment: Thanks, do you know if there is any plan to support this?

Comment: forgot to add this @robert