# Resize instance types on Container Engine cluster (w/o disk change)

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302233/resize-instance-types-on-container-engine-cluster) it says that there is no API for cluster node resizing. If you copy the old template when you are creating the new one it defaults to a SSD disk and you can change it back to a hard disk because when you open the image selector to change the disk type you can't find the Google Container Engine Image so you can't click Ok.

Is there a way around this?

Can you have different node types in the same cluster?

Can you resize the cluster without downtime (when you are changing the instance groups' template it kills the old node before starting the new one)?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

To quickly resize your cluster, you can use:

```
gcloud container clusters resize "<cluster name>" --size <new size>
```

There's also a new feature in GKE that lets you have nodes of different types: node pools. It allows you to create a new set of nodes on your cluster that has its own separate configuration and IGM backing it. The command to access it is currently in gcloud's "alpha" channel. Take a look at "gcloud container node-pools" for more info.

For example, to add a new node pool with 5 nodes comprised of "n1-standard-4" machines, run:

```
gcloud container node-pools create "bigger-pool" --cluster=my-cluster --machine-type=n1-standard-4 --num-nodes=5
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know if you can remove nodes from the clyster without downtime? (graceful shutdown)