# Is it possible to specifiy the boot disk type for a node pool?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to create a node pool with machines booting from a SSD with gcloud. If I tried creating a compute instance I would use the `--boot-disk-type` option to specify that, yet there seems to be no such option when creating a node pool.

I've checked the [documentation on creating node-pools](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/node-pools/create) and tried to specify the `--boot-disk-type` option anyway like so:

```
gcloud container node-pools create test-pool --cluster=my-cluster --machine-type=n1-highcpu-4 --disk-size=50 --num-nodes=2 --boot-disk-type=pd-ssd
```

Both without success. So my question is, whether it is even possible to create a node pool with machines booting from SSD. Maybe I'm trying to do it the wrong way. If this is not supported, what could be a possible workaround to get a node pool with machines booting from SSD?

---

I'm aware that I can add local SSDs to the machines using the `--local-ssd-count` option. Yet this does not seem to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option is supported now. You can specify boot disk type and size for node pools.

```
--disk-type=DISK_TYPE
    Type of the node VM boot disk. Defaults to pd-standard. DISK_TYPE must be one of: pd-standard, pd-ssd.

--disk-size=DISK_SIZE
    Size for node VM boot disks. Defaults to 100GB.
```

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/node-pools/create

Answer (score 1):

There isn't currently an option to specify the boot disk type for a node pool. The options you can specify about nodes are documented in the [NodeConfig](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/reference/rest/v1/NodeConfig) struct in the Google Container Engine API.

As an aside, for fields that exist in a managed instance group but not in the Google Container Engine API you can use the workaround posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302233/resize-instance-types-on-container-engine-cluster) but beware that your changes will not be "sticky" across node version upgrades.