# What to put for Kubernetes resource requests/limits?

Tags: kubernetes

I've seen [articles recommending](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2018/05/Kubernetes-best-practices-Resource-requests-and-limits.html) that resource requests/limit should be implemented. However, none I've found that discuss on *what* numbers to fill in.

For example, consider a container use zero CPU while idle, 80% under normal user requests and 200% CPU when hit by some rare requests:

- If I put the maximum, 2000m as CPU request then a core would sit idle most of the time
- On the other hand, if I request 800m and several pods are hitting their CPU limit at the same time the context switch overhead will kicks in

There are also cases like

- Internal tools that sit idle most of the time, then jump to 200% on active use
- Apps that have different peak time. For example, a SaaS that people use during working hours and a chatbot that start getting load after people leave work. It'd be nice if they could share the unused capacity.

Ideally [vertical pod autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler) would probably solve these problems automatically, but it is still in alpha today.

Comment: VPA has been released in beta as a CRD wiht K8s 1.12: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52565871/6309

Answer (score 1):

What I've been doing is to use telegraf to collect resource usage, and use the 95th percentile while the limit is set to 1 CPU and twice the memory request.

[image: Screenshot]

The problem with this method is

- App that utilize multicores during startup, then under a core throughout their life will take longer to starts. I've observed a 2 minutes Spring startup become 5 minutes
- Apps that are rarely used will have less resource reserved, and so have to rely on bursting capacity when it get invoked. This could be a problem if it has a surge in popularity.