# On Google can Kubernetes nodes be configured to have multiple network interfaces?

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

On Google Container Platform can Kubernetes nodes (or node pools) be configured to have multiple network interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately they cannot. All of the parameters that you can configure through the Google Kubernetes Engine API are [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1/NodeConfig).

If you want to customize the nodes beyond what is offered through the API you can create your own instance template as described in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302233/resize-instance-types-on-container-engine-cluster). The downside is that you will no longer be able to manage the nodes via the Google Kubernetes Engine API (e.g. for upgrading).