# Vertical Pod Autoscaling on Azure Kubernetes Service

Tags: azure-aks

Is Vertical Pod Autoscaling supported on Azure Kubernetes Service? I am unable to find any links or page on msdn with the details about it.

Comment: VPA is now released (as a CRD) with K8s 1.12: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52565871/6309

Comment: We are running v1.13.10 in AKS and VPA is still not accessible. Are there plans to support this?

Answer (score 3):

The Vertical Autoscaler is not supported in AKS, as the feature is still in Alpha in the upstream Kubernetes project. As the features matures in upstream it will be integrated into the service.

Comment: This can be installed as VPA preview feature. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/vertical-pod-autoscaler