# Modify GKE cluster instance details

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I have gke cluster with configuration of 3* 1vCPU , 3.75 GB RAM , 10 GB SSD .

I would like to modify the instance details :

- Increase SSD alone

Is it possible ? If so , can any one share  the reference link

Comment: Have a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302233/resize-instance-types-on-container-engine-cluster

Comment: This will update the entire instance configurations. i want only the disk (SSD) to get increased . where as core adn RAM can remains same. Say , increase current instance ssd of 10 gb to 100 GB in the gke cluster

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify nodes of a node pool once it has been created. The node pool creates a MIG template which is then used to provision the nodes. 
Any changes to a node pool require a new template and rolling updates.
For GKE Node pools, this is just not possible, you will need to create a new node pool with the configuration you want and [migrate your workloads to the new node pool](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/migrating-node-pool)